# Permanently caching results of Python class generation

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming

I am doing dynamic class generation that **could be** statically determined at "compile" time. The simple case that I have right now looks more or less like this:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.do_something()

def ClassFactory(*args):
    some_pre_processing()
    class GenericChild(Base):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.some_processing()
            super(GenericChild, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return GenericChild

Child1 = ClassFactory(1, 'Child_setting_value1')
Child2 = ClassFactory(2, 'Child_setting_value2')
Child3 = ClassFactory(3, 'Child_setting_value3')
```

On import, the Python interpreter seems to compile to bytecode, then execute the file (thus generating `Child1`, `Child2`, and `Child3`) once per Python instance.

**Is there a way to tell Python to compile the file, execute it once to unpack the `Child` classes, then compile that into the `pyc` file, so that the unpacking only happens once (even across successive executions of the Python script)?**

I have other use cases that are more complicated and expansive, so simply getting rid of the factory by hand-writing the `Child` classes is not really an option. Also, I would like to avoid an extra preprocessor step if possible (like using the C-style macros with the C preprocessor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd have to generate Python code instead where those classes are 'baked' to python code instead.

Use some form of string templating where you generate Python source code, save those to `.py` files, then bytecompile those.

However, the class generation happens only once on startup. Is it really that great a cost to generate these?

Comment: It doesn't cost much per class, but I have a lot of such cases and need to spawn many python instances often, so it adds up, especially under high load (in which case the initialization can take the bulk of the time for a short running program).

Comment: +1 for using a templating enginge when generating Python code.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no real need to have the child classes separate and you just want to have a 'standard configuration' for those particular sets of objects, you could just make your ObjectFactory a class with the configuration stored in there.  Each instance will be able to spit out GenericChildren with the appropriate configuration, completely bypassing the runtime generation of Classes (and the debugging headache associated with it).